# Как "на лету" удалить вводимые символы, если они не подходят условиям

Tags: javascript, jquery

Стоит задача: нужно запретить ввод символов кириллицы в поле пароля. Я решил использовать событие input, чтобы предотвратить все способы ввода, не только через клавиатуру, и написал вот такую проверку:

```js
$(document).on('input', '#USER_PASSWORD_POPUP', function() {
  var regexp = /[а-яё]/i;
  if (regexp.test($(this).val())) {
    if (!($('#USER_PASSWORD_POPUP-error-cirillica').length)) {
      $(this).parent().append('<label id="USER_PASSWORD_POPUP-error-cirillica" class="error" alt="Пароль не может содержать кириллицу.!" title="Пароль не может содержать кириллицу." for="USER_PASSWORD_POPUP">Пароль не может содержать кириллицу.</label>');
    }
    $(this).val('');
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#USER_PASSWORD_POPUP-error-cirillica').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" name="USER_PASSWORD" id="USER_PASSWORD_POPUP" placeholder="Пароль" class="form-control required password" maxlength="50" value="" autocomplete="on" tabindex="2" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

Проблема в том, что я хочу, чтобы не полностью очищался инпут, а удалялось только то, что только что было введено, не знаю, как лучше сделать, ну и в целом, если будут предложения по улучшению функции, буду рад принять)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$("#test").on('input', function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[а-яё]/gi,'')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" />
```

Comment: Идеально, спасибо большое